# MEGA and SIM900 ERROR when trying to post using "AT+HTTPACTION=1"

Tags: post, arduino, at-command, gprs, sim900

I have a SIM900 module connected to an Arduino MEGA, everything works fine except when I try to make a post request, it keeps showing ERROR after the AT+HTTPACTION=1 command is executed, by the SIM900 manual that ERROR message is related to "Mobile Equipment functionality". It worked perfectly but now it keeps showing that annoying ERROR.

This is my code: (I put a fake server address but mine works fine, I have tested it with postman)

```
void gprsSetup()
{
  Serial.println(F("Initializing GPRS module"));
  delay(1000);
  Serial1.flush();
  Serial.flush();

  Serial1.println("AT+CGATT?");                    
  delay(1000);                                     
  toSerial();                                      
  delay(1000);                                     

  Serial1.println("AT+CBAND?");                   
  delay(1000);                                     
  toSerial();                                      
  delay(1000);                                    

  Serial1.println("AT+CBAND=\"ALL_BAND\"\r\n");        
  delay(1000);                                     
  toSerial();                                      
  delay(1000);                                     

  Serial1.print("AT+CGDCONT=1,\"IP\",\"internet.movistar.ve\",\"\",0,0\r\n"); 
  delay(1000);                                     
  toSerial();                                      
  delay(1000);                                     

  Serial1.println("AT+CGDCONT?");                  
  delay(1000);                                     
  toSerial();                                      
  delay(1000);                                     

  Serial1.println("AT+IPR?\r\n");                  
  delay(1000);                                     
  toSerial();                                     
  delay(1000);                                      


  Serial1.println("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"CONTYPE\",\"GPRS\"\r\n"); 
  delay(1000);                                     
  toSerial();                                      
  delay(1000);                                     

  Serial1.println("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"APN\",\"internet.movistar.ve\"\r\n"); 
  delay(1000);                                     
  toSerial();                                      

  Serial1.println("AT+SAPBR=1,1\r\n");             
  delay(1000);                                     
  toSerial();                                      

  Serial1.println("AT+SAPBR=2,1\r\n");              
  delay(1000);                                     
  toSerial();                                      

  Serial1.println("AT+CSQ\r\n");                   
  delay(1000);                                     
  toSerial();                                      
  delay(1000);                                     

  Serial1.println("AT+SAPBR=2,1\r\n");              
  delay(1000);                                     
  toSerial();                                     

  Serial1.println("AT+HTTPINIT");                 
  delay(1000);                                     
  toSerial();                                      

  Serial1.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"CID\",1");        
  delay(1000);                                     
  toSerial();                                      


  jsonWriting();
  delay(3000);

  Serial1.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://myserverthatworks\"");        // not my real server address 
  delay(1000);                                     
  toSerial();                                      

  Serial1.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"CONTENT\",\"application/json\"");        
  delay(1000);                                     
  toSerial();                                      

  Serial1.println("AT+HTTPDATA=" + String(sendtoserver.length()) + ",10000");        // Server
  Serial.println(sendtoserver);
  delay(3000);                                     
  toSerial();                                      

  Serial1.println(sendtoserver);
  delay(1000);
  toSerial();

  Serial1.println("AT+HTTPACTION=1");
  delay(3000);
  toSerial();

  Serial1.println("AT+HTTPREAD");
  delay(2000);
  toSerial();
  delay(2000);

  Serial1.println("AT+HTTPTERM");
  delay(3000);
  toSerial();

}
```

And here's the output

[code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBDuC.png)

Comment: Use this command "AT+CMEE=2\r // Enable +CME ERROR: <err> result code and use verbose <err> values so your module won't respond with a simple "ERROR" string but will tell what is the exact problem. Save this parameter with AT&W\r command Is the rest of your connection msg (Network available/ logged to network etc) ok you just posted the http log part - please add the complete log as text to your question, delete creditentials before posting the new extended log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this command

```
 Serial1.println("AT+CMEE=2\r");   // Enable +CME ERROR: <err> result code               
 delay(1000);                                     
 toSerial();
```

and use verbose  values so your module won't respond with a simple "ERROR" string but will tell what is the exact problem. The do:

```
 Serial1.println("AT&W\r");   // save to be persistent after a reset               
 delay(1000);                                     
 toSerial();
```

Then when calling

```
 Serial1.println("AT+HTTPACTION=1");
 delay(3000);
 toSerial();
```

Youwill get the error - most likely with sim900 this will be

```
CME ERROR: 4    Operation not supported
```

meaning you have to send the strings via TCP/IP and using

```
  Serial1.println("AT+HTTPACTION=0");
```

If you get

```
CME ERROR: 3    Operation not allowed
```

your network operator does not allow this same as with not supported if

```
 CME ERROR: 30  No network service
```

up to 40 are network issues you can not influence and errors between 41 and 50 are missing pins,puks, passwords etc.
If you have any othererror message edit your question and I'll try to help

Comment: Thank you very much!! this is what I needed

Comment: I got Operation not allowed without a number, I dont get why because I made posts before with the same settings

Comment: Try a AT+HTTPTERM before you HTTPINIT to make sure all connections are closed and try to reduce the delay after HTTPACTION=1 to (500)